# Changing the location of the button in the 'react-sidebar' library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sidebar. I put the button in `section2` and it is located in`section1`. I can't scroll either. How do you move a button to `section2`? That the button does not move during scrolling.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2euk2q

Draw: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy3d6.jpg

```
import Sidebar from "react-sidebar";


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      sidebarOpen: false
    };
  }

  onSetSidebarOpen = (open) => {
    this.setState({ sidebarOpen: open });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <div className="section1">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitSed sollicitudin ante et dolor bibendum nec eleifend metus maximus Quisque eleifend massa sit amet efficitur rhoncus libero sem rutrum mauris eget suscipit diam mauris quis nisl Curabitur vitae pharetra massa Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Aenean tincidunt placerat velit vel ultrices nulla egestas id Ut commodoLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitSed sollicitudin ante et dolor bibendum nec eleifend metus maximus Quisque eleifend massa sit amet efficitur rhoncus libero sem rutrum mauris eget suscipit diam mauris quis nisl Curabitur vitae pharetra massa Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Aenean tincidunt placerat velit vel ultrices nulla egestas id Ut commodoLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitSed sollicitudin ante et dolor bibendum nec eleifend metus maximus Quisque eleifend massa sit amet efficitur rhoncus libero sem rutrum mauris eget suscipit diam mauris quis nisl Curabitur vitae pharetra massa Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Aenean tincidunt placerat velit vel ultrices nulla egestas id Ut commodo</p>
          </div>
          <div className="section2">
            <Sidebar
              sidebar={ 'Lorem ipsum'}
              open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
              onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
              styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white" } }}
              pullRight={true}
            >
            <button onClick={() => this.onSetSidebarOpen(true)}>
              Open sidebar
            </button>
          </Sidebar>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitSed sollicitudin ante et dolor bibendum nec eleifend metus maximus Quisque eleifend massa sit amet efficitur rhoncus libero sem rutrum mauris eget suscipit diam mauris quis nisl Curabitur vitae pharetra massa Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Aenean tincidunt placerat velit vel ultrices nulla egestas id Ut commodoLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitSed sollicitudin ante et dolor bibendum nec eleifend metus maximus Quisque eleifend massa sit amet efficitur rhoncus libero sem rutrum mauris eget suscipit diam mauris quis nisl Curabitur vitae pharetra massa Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Aenean tincidunt placerat velit vel ultrices nulla egestas id Ut commodoLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitSed sollicitudin ante et dolor bibendum nec eleifend metus maximus Quisque eleifend massa sit amet efficitur rhoncus libero sem rutrum mauris eget suscipit diam mauris quis nisl Curabitur vitae pharetra massa Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Aenean tincidunt placerat velit vel ultrices nulla egestas id Ut commodo</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.section1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.section2 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.section2 button {
  left: 200px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Sidebar` component has it's own `CSS`,

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
```

You need to add `postion:relative` to your `section2`.

```
.section2 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  position: relative;     //Add this
}
```

Now your button will be at top left corner, you can move that button using `CSS` wherever you want.

```
.section2 button{
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```